# creating a String[] dynamically from a List<String>

Tags: java, android

I should create this:

```
listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, new String[] { "data1","data2" }));
```

But I don't know how to create `new String[]{...}` dynamically.

I have this code and I should use the `CitazioniOutput` array:

```
String[] citazioni = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.citazioni);
List<String> CitazioniOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String value : citazioni) {
    CitazioniOutput.add(value);
}
```

**I tried:**

```
listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, CitazioniOutput));
//and
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,CitazioniOutput);
listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, adapter));
```

But nothing changed: it says

```
The constructor is undefined
```

How can I convert the `List<String>` into a `String[]`?

Comment: Use `listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, CitazioniOutput.toArray(new String[CitazioniOutput.size()])));` But why don't you modify your adapter to take a List instead?

Comment: Why are you not just passing citazioni, which is a String array? I don't see the point in converting it to a list and then back to an array...

Comment: ZouZou Thanks a lot, you saved me :D
Can you link me a page that explains how to modify the adapter to take a List? :)
@katzoft Because I should edit every item :)

Comment: As katzoft asked, why convert `String[]` to `List<String>` then back to `String[]`? Just use the original `String[]`.

Comment: @ADTC I said because then I should edit every item ;)

Comment: @ADTC Note that the adapter will call `Arrays.asList(citazioni)` under the hood. So you won't be able to call the add/remove the items in your adapter, since Arrays.asList returns a fixed size list. That's why I think it's better to pass a non fixed size List directly in the constructor of the custom adapter.

Comment: @ZouZou I think you mean to address your comment to the OP `:)` but yes, that makes sense. The adapter constructor should be accepting the original `List`.

Comment: @ADTC Both the OP and you (you were saying to use the original array) `=)`

Comment: Well, yes, but the original is a `String[]` so it already prevents you from using add/remove. Then the OP converts it into a `List<String>`, then back to a `String[]`, then inside the adapter back to a `List<String>`. Not sure what the point is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method from the [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) class:  `List.toArray(Object[]);`

```
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    String[] strings = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(strings);
```